# remove the inherited CSS value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove the value of an inherited CSS property using Jquery.

```css
.class1 #id1 div.class2 input.class-input{
    border-color: #bbb3b9 #c7c1c6 #c7c1c6;
}
```

Anyone tell me how to remove this "border-color".

Thank.

Comment: i use $(".class-input").css("border-color",""). But it won't do anything. it can change color but not remove.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class for example

```
.new_class{
    border-color: #00ffdd !important;
}
```

!important does the trick!

[Check this](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: that class override  my class ex:
 .class1 #id1 div.class2 input.class-input .myclass{
    border-color: red;
}
so i want remove it by jquery so that my class can active

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, but you'll have to assign a value to the border-color property. You can use `transparent` though:

```
$('.class-input').css('border-color', 'transparent');
```

**Edit:** Or you can disable the whole border:

```
$('.class-input').css('border', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either swap the on your div to change the color, or set the border color to empty using

```
$(".class1").css("border-color", "");
```

But I would recommend swapping out the class using the removeClass and addClass JQuery functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to keep the width of the border:

```
border-color: transparent;
```

If you want to remove the border all together

```
border: 0;
```

**Edit:** `border: none;` will give your the same result

So your jquery could look something like this:

```
$(".class-input").css("border","0");
```

However I would suggest using CSS if you don't need to make it animated. Since you raised the concern about `.class1 #id1 div.class2 input.class-input.myclass` (I'm assuming that's what you mean since you wouldn't be throwing a div into an input box.

You can use the CSS pseudo-selector `:not`

```
.class1 #id1 div.class2 input.class-input:not(.my-class){
   border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle this is to add another reference to give your override code a higher specificity.

```
.class1 #id1 div.class2 input.class-input [#MyNewID]{
border: none;
}
```

This removes the border for the area where you have added the ID so that if you are using this same format in other pages you can add an additional ID on the element on the page where you want the border to "disappear"

Please don't use !important this is a lazy way to override code and is not necessary 95% of the time.  It will also cause you problem later when you are trying to change this if you are pushing down site wide skins.